# Does .NET FileSystemWatcher work with Mono on Mac OS?

Tags: c#, .net, macos, mono

Can I write a Microsoft .NET programm with a FileSystemWatcher and expect it to work under Mac OS X with Mono without changes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it will work without changes. **Mono includes a FileSystemWatcher for all platforms.**

Keep in mind that your code might want to use [Path.PathSeperator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.pathseparator.aspx) to be more compatible with the different ways directory names are formatted on different platforms.

Comment: You would want to use all the Path.* members to avoid cross-platform issues.

Comment: actually, instead of `Path.PathSeperator` it's usually much more appropriate to use `Path.Combine(firstPartOfPath, secondPartOfPathOrPossiblyFilename)`.

Comment: Note that the implementation on Mac does not catch `Changed` events. See [this bug report](https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=428270). All I've found was [this workaround](http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/mono-osx/2008-October/001664.html).

Comment: Also keep in mind that it does not work (correctly) for any files other than those directly under the root directory. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16519000/filesystemwatcher-under-mono-watching-subdirs.

Answer (score 1):

As of November 2011, it exists and works for some uses, but not all.

For example, LastWrite and Size dont seem to work on OSX.

Comment: Hi is this still the case? I'm finding I don't get Changed events on MacOS with MONO FSW....

Comment: I unfortunately gave up on this API and stopped using it. Instead, I wrote a custom solution using the CoreServices FSEvents API.

Comment: Hey Danny - any chance you can help ? I'm trying to do the same but my call to CFRunLoop kills TeamCity tests (my test in MonoDevelop run fine). Any ideas why???

Comment: I have zero familiarity with TeamCity.

Comment: Hi Danny thanks for the feedback. We've licensed Xamarain.Mac which has a FSEvents watcher working....